# How to select nth child element in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a structure like

```
<li id="step1_li">
 <a>...</a>
 <a>...</a>
</li>
```

I want to select 2nd 'a' tag,

i am using like

```
$('#step1_li :nth-child(2) a').addClass("hide");
```

But it is not working, please suggest where i am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are writing it wrong. it's like in CSS

`$('#step1_li  a:nth-child(2)').addClass("hide");`

if you want to find an `nth`  element then you need to attach `:nth-` to that element, in this case the `a` element

```js
$('#step1_li  a:nth-child(2)').addClass("hide");
```

```css
.hide { color:red;font-weight:bold}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="step1_li">
 <a>...</a>
 <a>...</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#step1_li a:nth-child(2)").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<li id="step1_li">
 <a>1</a>
 <a>2</a>
 <a>3</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "li a:nth-child(2)" ).addClass("hide");
```

Use this....